# Firebase Auth - how to refresh access token without current user object

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am accessing my backend with an access token obtained from firebase auth the following way:

1. login via email & password
2. receive the current user object
3. obtain the token from the user object
4. store the token locally to allow furher access to my backend (which uses firebase admin to validate the token)

This works, as long as the access token is stale.
This may as well work, if the application remains open and an 403 due to an expired token can be catched (I can just reuse the current user object to obtain a new token). However, if the token expires while the app is closed, opening it again (no more user object) results in forcing the user to reenter its credentials, does it?

One way that came to my mind was using the custom tokens functionality:
I could send the refresh token to the client after a login, which then stores it and would use it to log in (in an automatic manner) instead of using the credentials.
But the word "custom" made me think that I am on the wrong way somehow. There surely must be an easy way to do this with the intended functions.

Can any one help me out with this?

Greetings,

Codehai

Comment: The token expires and automatically refreshes itself every hour as needed. Instead of storing it, just ask for the token for each new task.

Comment: In the unity implementation I can't just aquire a new token after a restart without specifiying credentials. There are 2 options for this email and password or custom token.

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you saying the user has to log in again each time?  That doesn't sound right on any platform.

Comment: Thats right, if 1 hour passes and the access token expires from firebase side, the user is forced to log in again. As I pointed out above, this does not happen, if the user stays in the application, I know firebase refreshes its token then. But think of a mobile app. If you don't use it for 1 hour and open it up again, this problem will occur.

Comment: That's not the way it's supposed to work.  It should refresh automatically.

Comment: It does, but not if the app remains closed for an hour --> Because the app restarted you don't have a pointer to the user object (no way to call getToken) and the old, stored access token is not valid any more.

Comment: I have the exact same problem... this does not refresh. I set up the observer specifically meant to run on id token state change... i.e `firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged` ... this code just doesn't run after the hour has come and gone. I'm using this in a React Native Expo app.. and it's driving me insane!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this listener refreshes the token automatically, **won't work in editor**.

For my code to work, somehow I have to add TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() on all Firebase Tasks..

```
 void Start()
    {
      auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
      auth.IdTokenChanged += IdTokenChanged;
    }

void IdTokenChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth senderAuth = sender as Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth;
        if (senderAuth == auth && senderAuth.CurrentUser != null && !fetchingToken)
        {
            fetchingToken = true;
            senderAuth.CurrentUser.TokenAsync(true).ContinueWith(
                task =>
                {

                    if (task.IsCanceled)
                    { 
                        Debug.Log("canceled");
                    }

                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        foreach (var errors in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
                        {
                            Debug.Log(errors.InnerException.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    Debug.Log("New Token: " + task.Result);
                    // save task.Result
                    fetchingToken = false;
                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
    }

private void OnDestroy()
    {
        auth.IdTokenChanged -= IdTokenChanged;
    }
```